# Is there any true evidence for any miraculous event written in the bible?

Tags: bible, biblical-reliability

Is there trustworthy evidence of any event written in the bible ?

For instance events like-

Garden of Eden,
The great flood & Noah's ark,
Moses & Parting of the red sea,
Miracles of Prophets,
Miracles of Jesus like transforming water into wine at marriage ceremony,conversion of bread & fish into large number of those, curing people with disease,etc,
Miracles of Apostles

Comment: In the interests of enhacing understanding, a huge amount of what is in the Bible is completely backed up by historical evidence. Most of the later historical figures unquestionably existed in the times and places they are described. The nation of Israel and the cities and places mentioned in the Bible existed, in the places they are described.

Comment: What about evidence for the 'events' (not people or places) described in the bible ?

Comment: We allow questions for archaeological evidence or historical evidence outside of the Bible for events in the Bible, but you do need to ask about them one at a time.

Comment: I am asking evidence for 'any' miraculous event you can think of. Your statement seems there are plenty evidences for many such events. So all I need to do is to select any of those & ask it here?

Comment: You might find [this article](https://answersingenesis.org/archaeology/the-walls-of-jericho/) on the Walls of Jericho to be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

In your recent [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68028/according-to-physics-do-our-visual-thoughts-possibly-others-appear-to-be-not) about human thought you speak of a realm in which physics does not apply. And you speak of communication to, and perhaps from, this other realm. I call this the realm of spirit.

In your recent question you speak of 'time' which existed before time. I call this 'eternity' for the terms 'infinite time' or 'time before time' are clearly contradictory and illogical terms.

This other sphere, this other realm, this other kind of existence, is that of eternal spirit. And from that realm came a voice which said :

> I am that I am. [Exodus 3:14, KJV.]

And the voice came from a flame. And the flame was in a bush.

And the bush, supernaturally, was not consumed . . . .

. . . . proving that the voice came from a realm where physics does not apply and where there is no time, just eternal Being.

You had already answered your own question, here, with your other question, there. I have just assisted by applying biblical terminology to concepts with which you were already familiar.

Moses heard that voice about three and a half thousand years ago. But the voice of the Eternal Spirit still speaks, timelessly, unfailingly . . . .

. . . to those that have ears to hear it.

Comment: I don't speak in that question about a realm in which physics doesn't apply. Atleast that's what I meant personally. I think you misunderstood it. Infact, I have tried to explain it with as much physics I know of. I don't speak of time before time. Infact I wrote- 'It is meaningless to think of time before the beginning of time'.

Comment: @CuriousMind9 Your article mentioned the concepts of 1. 'Physically inaccessible higher dimensions' and 2. 'time before the beginning of time'. Whether or not you accept these concepts to be real, or not, it is a fact that you are aware of the concepts.

Comment: In my question in philosophy SE , I was of the opinion that whatever images we think it must occupy some space geometrically. I am talking about geometric info rather than the info which produces it. The info which produces it is in our brain. Because no one can see what another person imagines, I suggest it must be in some higher dimensions. These imageries exist as long as we imagine & don't have existence of their own in those dimensions.

Comment: Hence just because we imagine something, does that mean its authentic? We can imagine anything our senses have accustomed to including whatever that has never happened or that never will happen. For instance I can imagine myself to be the president of USA. The imagery can exist in a higher dimension transiently as long as I imagine. But does that mean I am the president of USA or will become so?

Comment: You are coming up with the verses written in the bible (or what characters in the bible ‘felt’) as the evidence themselves. I am asking here for real evidence for the 'events' in the bible. I am not questioning here the existence of God. (Infact I believe that there is ,the reason being totally different).

Comment: Neither I am questioning here the existence of a realm beyond our reach. I am asking here real tangible evidence for any miraculous event (not characters or places) in the bible. I believe even if its miracle it will leave its footprints in our 3D world though we may not able to understand the miracle itself. Because I accept we have our own limitations.

Comment: @CuriousMind9 It is a matter of faith. You either believe the Divine record or you do not. You either hear God Almighty speaking (via his written record) or you do not. You are either obedient to his word - or you are not. I leave the matter with you. Regards.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked. This isn't an example of evidence of something, it's a *possible explanation* for how something - which *might* have happened - may have occurred.

Comment: As an analogy, if I told you an a celebrity walked into my house and you asked me for proof (video, photo, and so on) of it happening, me replying "Well, maybe I left the door unlocked" isn't *proof* of it happening, but an explanation as to *how* it may have happened. In fact, I'm sure you'd be quite confused by my response